# Is there any way to update a column of a table with WTD values in one go?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to update a table with WTD values for specific date. Everytime while updating it I have to enter the date manually in the condition. Is there any method to pass the date values dynamically in conditions such that my WTD values get updated in one go?

Here is my update query:

```
update table1, (Select sum(sales) as sales from table1 where
day between subdate('2016-09-01', Interval weekday('2016-09-01') Day) and '2016-09-01') src 
set WTD_Sales=src.sales
where day='2016-09-01'
```

So here I want to replace the statically added date '2016-09-01' with a variable that can fetch date from same table itself row by row dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks wrong to me. Change it like below using a `JOIN`. Assuming there is a `id` column present in the table.

```
update table1 t1
join ( Select sum(sales) as sales, id, some_date_column
 from table1 
where day between subdate('2016-09-01', Interval weekday('2016-09-01') Day) 
and '2016-09-01') src on t1.id = src.id
set t1.WTD_Sales = src.sales
where t1.day = src.some_date_column;
```

Comment: The query is working fine for me. My only concern is instead of puting dates statically in the query can we just pass dates dynamically such that for every row WTD values get updated and date value keeps on changing in the condition accordingly. Here I am trying to update WTD values for whole table.

Comment: What you mean by that? what you mean by date gets changed dynamically? clarify more on this

Comment: I would want to pass date used in condition as per the date I have in Day column for that particular row. For eg. if I want to update WTD column for row that has date '2016-11-25' in Day column then query should get this date feeded automatically in the condition used. Is there anyway to perform this type updating?

Comment: @NeelamChoudhary, in that case did you checked and tried the suggested query in answer. it exactly does that

Comment: Yes I tried the suggested query but it is updating only for first day of the week